# VBA UserForm refresh

Tags: vba, userform

I have a word VBA UserForm that I am using as a Leaderboard to track results from a SQL query as it updates. Is there a way to auto refresh the form once it is launched every 10 minutes? I have tried this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim AgingSQL As String

cnn.ConnectionString = "DATABASE INFO"
cnn.Open

AgingSQL = "SQL QUERY"
rst.Open AgingSQL, cnn
rst.MoveFirst
With UserForm1.AgingLeaderboard -- List Box I am using to display info
     .Clear
     Do
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = rst![StatusBy]
        .List(i, 1) = rst![Count]
        i = i + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
rst.Close
**Call Refresh**
End Sub

Sub Refresh()
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "UserForm_Initialize"
End Sub
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: i would put your sql in a function and have a loop that waits ten minutes and then calls that function. set the loop counter length afterwards. OR you could set up a task in your task managers to call the sub every ten minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `Application.OnTime` to execute anything other than a macro - a public, parameterless method exposed by a standard, procedural module.

`UserForm_Initialize` isn't a *macro* - it's an event handler, that handles the `Initialize` event of a `UserForm` object.. which is only ever called once per instance, when the object, well, *initializes*. You should **never**, ever need to explicitly call an event handler. If you find yourself doing that, alarm bells should go off, big huge red flags should fly, *something is being done terribly wrong*.

Take everything you have in `UserForm_Initialize` and move it to a public `RefreshLeaderboard` method - you won't need to handle `Initialize`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RefreshLeaderboard()
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim AgingSQL As String

    cnn.ConnectionString = "DATABASE INFO"
    cnn.Open

    AgingSQL = "SQL QUERY"
    rst.Open AgingSQL, cnn
    rst.MoveFirst
    With AgingLeaderboard '-- note: was With UserForm1.AgingLeaderBoard

         .Clear
         Do
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = rst![StatusBy]
            .List(i, 1) = rst![Count]
            i = i + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF
    End With
    rst.Close    
End Sub
```

Now you need a macro that you can schedule, that can access the form instance.

```
Option Explicit
Private leaderboardForm As MyAwesomeForm ' whatever the UserForm class name is

Public Sub ShowLeaderboard()
    Set leaderboardForm = New MyAwesomeForm
    ScheduleNextRefresh
    leaderboardForm.Show 'vbModal?
    'Set leaderBoardForm = Nothing '' only if the form was modal and not X'd-out
End Sub

Public Sub ScheduleNextRefresh()
    If Not leaderboardForm Is Nothing Then
        leaderboardForm.RefreshLeaderboard
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "ScheduleNextRefresh"
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll probably want to handle the `QueryClose` event in the form's code-behind, to handle it being closed and/or destroyed by a user that clicks the [X] button.

Comment: So I went ahead and implemented your recommendations, but now I am not getting any of my data in the various Labels and Listbox that I have. The Userform still pops up, but all I have are the defaults 0s. When I try to assign the same values to a messagebox, it shows the appropriate numbers. Do you have any idea why the information wouldn't post to the Form?

Comment: Make sure you're calling `.Show` on the same instance as the one your refreshing. Forms have a default instance, when you do `UserForm1.Show` you're using that default instance, and you don't want that.

Comment: The only time I am calling .Show is where you specified at leaderboardForm.Show

Comment: @CodyCook Oh shoot, glancing at the `UserForm_Initialize` code I copied from your OP I just realized what it was - `With UserForm1.AgingLeaderboard` is updating the default instance, not the instance it's in. I don't know who in the MSForms API design team thought giving forms a default instance was a brilliant thing to do, but anyway that's what's going on. Make sure you NEVER use the default instance anywhere, and everything will be fine.

Comment: That fixed the data issue, now to wait to see if the numbers update when the data is updated, thanks so much!

Comment: @CodyCook see [UserForms best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19036/best-practices#t=201704041426108881089) for more information about coding OOP forms.